# Allen Browne's Concatenate Function with 2 criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have been happily using Allen Browne's VBA:

```vb
Option Compare Database

Public Function ConcatRelated(strField As String, _
    strTable As String, _
    Optional strWhere As String, _
    Optional strOrderBy As String, _
    Optional strSeparator = ", ") As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   Generate a concatenated string of related records.
    'Return:    String variant, or Null if no matches.
    'Arguments: strField = name of field to get results from and concatenate.
    '           strTable = name of a table or query.
    '           strWhere = WHERE clause to choose the right values.
    '           strOrderBy = ORDER BY clause, for sorting the values.
    '           strSeparator = characters to use between the concatenated values.
    'Notes:     1. Use square brackets around field/table names with spaces or odd characters.
    '           2. strField can be a Multi-valued field (A2007 and later), but strOrderBy cannot.
    '           3. Nulls are omitted, zero-length strings (ZLSs) are returned as ZLSs.
    '           4. Returning more than 255 characters to a recordset triggers this Access bug:
    '               http://allenbrowne.com/bug-16.html
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset         'Related records
    Dim rsMV As DAO.Recordset       'Multi-valued field recordset
    Dim strSql As String            'SQL statement
    Dim strOut As String            'Output string to concatenate to.
    Dim lngLen As Long              'Length of string.
    Dim bIsMultiValue As Boolean    'Flag if strField is a multi-valued field.

    'Initialize to Null
    ConcatRelated = Null

    'Build SQL string, and get the records.
    strSql = "SELECT " & strField & " FROM " & strTable
    If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
        strSql = strSql & " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If
    If strOrderBy <> vbNullString Then
        strSql = strSql & " ORDER BY " & strOrderBy
    End If
    Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)
    'Determine if the requested field is multi-valued (Type is above 100.)
    bIsMultiValue = (rs(0).Type > 100)

    'Loop through the matching records
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If bIsMultiValue Then
            'For multi-valued field, loop through the values
            Set rsMV = rs(0).Value
            Do While Not rsMV.EOF
                If Not IsNull(rsMV(0)) Then
                    strOut = strOut & rsMV(0) & strSeparator
                End If
                rsMV.MoveNext
            Loop
            Set rsMV = Nothing
        ElseIf Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
            strOut = strOut & rs(0) & strSeparator
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

    'Return the string without the trailing separator.
    lngLen = Len(strOut) - Len(strSeparator)
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ConcatRelated = Left(strOut, lngLen)
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    'Clean up
    Set rsMV = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ConcatRelated()"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

This allows the user to use `ConcatRelated("variable", "table", criteria)`

My current need I believe will require modifications to the VBA, which I know little of, or some SQL that I am not currently thinking of.

I currently have `qryDoseDays` that is pulling `SubjectNumber`, `RECDATE` from `tblDump` with SQL:

```
SELECT d.SubjectNumber, d.RECDATE, Count(d.RECTIME) AS DailyDoses
FROM (SELECT dd.SubjectNumber, dd.RECDATE, dd.RECTIME FROM tblDump AS dd LEFT JOIN tblL ON dd.SubjectNumber=tblL.SubjectNumber WHERE dd.RECDATE<>tblL.[2])  AS d
GROUP BY d.SubjectNumber, d.RECDATE
HAVING Count(d.RECTIME)>2
ORDER BY d.SubjectNumber, d.RECDATE;
```

So, there are variables `SubjectNumber`, `RECDATE` and `RECTIME`. I need `RECTIME` values concatenated per row grouped by both `SubjectNumber` and `RECDATE`. I can only seem to use his function for either `SubjectNumber` or `RECDATE` but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your `SubjectNumber` and `RECDATE` values as the third argument (*strWhere*) to `ConcatRelated()`.

```
SELECT
    q.SubjectNumber,
    q.RECDATE,
    q.DailyDoses,
    ConcatRelated
        (
            "RECTIME",
            "tblDump",
            "SubjectNumber=" & q.SubjectNumber
                & " AND RECDATE="
                & Format(q.RECDATE, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
        ) AS RECTIME_list
FROM qryDoseDays AS q
```

I assumed `SubjectNumber` is numeric data type and `RECDATE` is Date/Time type.  If either of those assumptions is wrong, you'll have to adapt the SQL to handle the actual data types.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was incorrectly formatting the SQL re: the RECDATE variable. This worked exactly as hoped.