# Split multiple results in columns instead of rows on Access Report

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am very new to Access Reports and I am trying to do something that I have no clue to be honest.

Raw data of my query is like that:

[image]

Report I made look like this:

[image]

As you can see on the image, the field PapelEncomendas.Quantidade have multiple results for that item. I would like to get each result on a new column instead of row. The other field will always have only one result.

Thanks for any help

Bye

Comment: Edit question to show sample of raw data as text table. Possibly you need a CROSSTAB query. Or VBA, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752239/allen-brownes-concatenate-function-with-2-criteria

Comment: Have you tried PIVOT?